# ¿Cómo hago este ordenamiento en C?

Tags: c, ordenamiento

quisiera saber cómo hago para ordenar y que me queden los nombres correspondiente a los salarios. Se ordenan los numeros/salarios pero los nombres  no y me quedan mal. Acá les dejo el código :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 struct  SALARIOS {
   int mes_1;
   int mes_2;
   int mes_3;
  float promedio;

  };

struct PERSONAS
{
char nombre[30];
char sexo[10];
  };
int main(){
struct SALARIOS salarios[5];
struct PERSONAS personas[5];
int i, j, k;
int nombre_a_buscar;
int suma=0;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Ingrese su nombre : ");
    scanf("%s", &personas[i].nombre);

    printf("Ingrese su Sexo F / M : ");
    scanf("%s", &personas[i].sexo);

    printf("Ingrese el sueldo del MES 1 : ");
    scanf("%i", &salarios[i].mes_1);

    printf("Ingrese el sueldo del MES 2  : ");
    scanf("%i", &salarios[i].mes_2);

    printf("Ingrese el sueldo del MES 3 : ");
    scanf("%i", &salarios[i].mes_3);

}

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    suma = salarios[j].mes_1 + salarios[j].mes_2 + salarios[j].mes_3;
    salarios[j].promedio = suma/3;

}
for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    printf("El promedio de : %s\t es de : \t%.2f ", personas[k].nombre, salarios[k].promedio);
    printf("\n\n\n");
}

//printf("Las personas con los 3 mejores salarios son : ");
int pos ; int aux ; int w ; int x;

for(x=0;x<5;x++){
    pos = x;
    aux = salarios[x].promedio;

    while((pos>0)&&(aux < salarios[pos-1].promedio)){
        salarios[pos].promedio = salarios[pos-1].promedio;
        pos--;
    }
    salarios[pos].promedio = aux;
}
printf("Las personas con los 3 mejores salarios son : ");
for(x=4;x>=0;x--){
    printf("Nombre: %s ", personas[x].nombre);
    printf(" Salario : %f ",salarios[x].promedio);
    printf("\n\n\n");
}

getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: mejor usa una matriz, en vez de estar guardando por separado cada cosa. matriz_personal[n][2];
as columna 0 = nombre
la columna 1 = salario

Answer (score 0):

Ok el detalle esta en que estas reacomodando tus salarios, pero nunca los nombres de empleados

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++){
    pos = x;
    aux = salarios[x].promedio;

    while((pos>0)&&(aux < salarios[pos-1].promedio)){
        salarios[pos].promedio = salarios[pos-1].promedio;//<-Aquí reacomodas tu salario
    //pero no reacomodas empleado
//talvez
//personas[pos].nombre = personas[pos-1].nombre
        pos--;
    }
    salarios[pos].promedio = aux;
}
```

Así que tambien tendrias que reacomodar tus personas
También date cuenta que solo estas reacomodando las propiedades y no los objetos tal cual, si tu inspeccionas te van a salir cruzados tus elementos, osea el promedio de tus meses ya no corresponde (porque el promedio lo moviste de lugar)
También podrias agregar el salario a la misma struct Persona
o hacer otra que se llame empleado y tenga una persona y un salario, eso te lo dejo a concideracion. Pero de esta manera tendrías un solo objeto para ordernar y tendrias mas control.